# Sails doesn't start if hook use domain

Tags: node.js, error-handling, dns, sails.js

I create a Sails.js server that can use third party code on hook initialization. 
I want to use domain to catch error safely but when an error occurred, error is catch correctly but sails server doesn't start with this error :

```
error: Error: The hook `myhook` is taking too long to load.
Make sure it is triggering its `initialize()` callback, or else set `sails.config.plugins._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 20000)
    at tooLong [as _onTimeout] (/.../node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:92:21)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15) { [Error: The hook `plugins` is taking too long to load.
Make sure it is triggering its `initialize()` callback, or else set `sails.config.plugins._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 20000)] code: 'E_HOOK_TIMEOUT' }
```

Here is my hook code :

```
module.exports = function (sails)
{
  return {
    initialize  : function (next)
    {
      var scope = this;
      sails.after(["hook:services:loaded", "hook:orm:loaded"], function ()
      {
          scope.loadPlugins(next);
      });
    },
    loadPlugins : function (next)
    {
      var fs   = require("fs");
      var path = require("path");

      fs.readdir("plugins", function (err, list)
      {

        var domain = require('domain').create();
        domain.on('error', function (err)
          {
            // handle the error safely
            sails.log.error(err);
            sails.log.error(pluginname);
          });
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
          var pluginname                           = list[i];
          var plugin                               = require(__dirname + "/../../plugins/" + pluginname + "/" + pluginname + ".js");

          sails.services.pluginservice[pluginname] = plugin;
          domain.run(function ()
          {
            if (plugin.init)
            {
              plugin.init(function (err)
              {
                if (err)
                {
                  sails.log.error(err);
                }
              });
            }
          });

        }
        if (next)
        {
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on next method and it's called correctly. But sails doesn't see it and make a timeout.
I use node.js v0.12.2 and sails v0.11.0